# Trying to get fastcgi to work in nginx and c++

Tags: c++, nginx, fastcgi

Below is my c++ code and my config file.

when I run `spawn-fcgi -a120.0.0.1 -p9000 -n ./rtb.o`

I get this error

```
spawn-fcgi: exec failed: Exec format error
```

Here is my c++ code that I complied as rtb.o

```
#include "fcgi_stdio.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
  {
      int count = 1;
      while(FCGI_Accept() >= 0)
          printf("Content-type: text/html\r\n"
                 "\r\n"
                 "<title>FastCGI Hello!</title>"
                 "<h1>FastCGI Hello!</h1>"
                 "Request number %d running on host \n",
                  ++count);
      return 0;
  }
```

So, what did I do wrong?

Comment: Note: sudo spawn-fcgi -d /var/www/ -f /var/www/rtb.o -a 127.0.0.1 -p 9000    this worked and gave me the output spawn-fcgi: child spawned successfully: PID: 3671

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attempting to run a program called `rtb.o`?  Is this an object file or an executable?  You might want to show us how you compile your program.  If you're doing something like

```
g++ -c rtb.cpp
```

Then you will get an object file and you need to link it to get a working program.  Try to run it from your terminal using `./rtb.o`.  If it prints the same message, then you've got an object file and need to try something like this instead:

```
g++ -o rtb rtb.cpp
```

Remember to add a reference to the FCGI library when you link (use the `-l` option).

Comment: THis is the outpout when I build  
**** Build of configuration Debug for project rtb ****

make all 
Building file: ../src/rtb.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I/usr/local/include/ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/rtb.d" -MT"src/rtb.d" -o"src/rtb.o" "../src/rtb.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/rtb.cpp
 
Building target: rtb
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -L/usr/local/include/ -lfcgi++ -o"rtb"  ./src/rtb.o   
Finished building target: rtb

Comment: That says that it compiles a program named `rtb`, not `rtb.o`.  The `rtb.o` file is an intermediate file produced during compilation.  Is the command in your question accurate?  Are you really trying to run `./rtb.o`?

Comment: Thanks a lot!  g++ -L/usr/local/include/ -lfcgi++ -o rtb rtb.cpp